# Service worker cache in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, caching, axios, service-worker

I have an application in VueJs using axios, service worker and recently I'm struggling with what it seems a new bug that came with our last update. A bit of context first, the URL in production of this application was for example **lorem.ipsum.com** and we changed to **dolor.ipsum.com**. With that in mind everything is working like the application and redirect from **lorem.ipsum** to **dolor.ipsum**. But the thing is that if I access **lorem.ipsum** the URL only changes when the user press CTRL+SHIFT+R to reload the page and what I wanted was that when the user access **lorem.ipsum** the redirect happened automatically to **dolor.ipsum**.

Here's the current state of the code

```js
import { register } from "register-service-worker";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready() {
      console.log(
        "App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n"
      );
    },
    registered() {
      console.log("Service worker has been registered.");
    },
    cached() {
      console.log("Content has been cached for offline use.");
    },
    updatefound() {
      console.log("New content is downloading.");
    },
    updated() {
      console.log("New content is available; please refresh.");
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.reload();
      }, 1000)
    },
    offline() {
      console.log("No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.");
    },
    error(error) {
      console.error("Error during service worker registration:", error);
    },
  });
}
```

Edit 1: After adding the code below to use the application version to update/redirect the content it worked but only for those who never accessed the application before (because of cookies). When I delete all cookies, it works. So now I want a way to deal with those cookies for all users because we can't ask for all users to delete them.

```js
workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({ prefix: 'd4' });

const LATEST_VERSION = process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION;

self.addEventListener('activate', () => {
  if (caches) {
    caches.keys().then((arr) => {
      arr.forEach((key) => {
        if (key.indexOf('d4-precache') < -1) {
          caches.delete(key).then(() => console.log(`%c Cleared ${key}`, 'background: #333; color: #ff0000'));
        } else {
          caches.open(key).then((cache) => {
            cache.match('version').then((res) => {
              if (!res) {
                cache.put('version', new Response(LATEST_VERSION, { status: 200, statusText: LATEST_VERSION }));
              } else if (res.statusText !== LATEST_VERSION) {
                caches.delete(key).then(() => console.log(`%c Cleared Cache ${LATEST_VERSION}`));
              } else console.log(`%c Great you have the latest version ${LATEST_VERSION}`);
            });
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
});

workbox.skipWaiting();
workbox.clientsClaim();

self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings();
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
```